# How do i serve a file with different name in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Lets say i get a GET request to file `/dir/01/23/file.ext`. I would like to serve the file `/dir/01/23` which is an extensionless file. The filename should be `file.ext` rather then 03 and the mime of `.ext` should be used. How do i write a rule in nginx to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite  ^/dir/01/23/file.ext$  /dir/01/23  break;
```

or

```
rewrite  ^(.*)/file.ext$  $1  break;
```

you may also need to specify dedicated location. For example:

```
location /dir {
  root   $docroot;
}
```

Comment: I believe that will work but i wont be able to try until tomorrow. Nice answer